# 100% ESM module world - what it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

While reading about tree shaking in webpack documentation, I came across this sentence:

> In a 100% ESM module world, identifying side effects is straightforward. However, we aren't there just yet.

What do they mean by "100% ESM module" and how it is different from the current `import` and `export` that we already use today?

reference: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about understanding an English sentence, not about programming.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think it's on-topic, it's asking about the meaning of a particular programming term which I think is well-defined

Comment: would be nicer to add a link to the doc @user9078913

Comment: @CertainPerformance: The meaning of the phrase "100% ESM module world" is really the same as the meaning of the phrase "100% electric car world" or "100% COVID-19 vaccinated world". Parsing the phrase is independent of any sort of programming knowledge, and requires only knowledge of English grammar and idioms. I use the rule "if you can replace the programming related terms with terms from another field without changing the question, then the question is not a question about programming, but a question which occurred *during* programming." It's basically a boat programming question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand the term in plain English, what I did not understand is how is it different that our current `import` and `export` module system.  @srknzl I added a reference to the docs, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you're reading is contrasting two types of scripts:

- Scripts which expose *everything* they do through what they `import` and `export`
- Scripts which do something *in addition* to importing and exporting (this could be seen as a "side effect")

Consider a big library, one that installs itself as a namespace on the global object to expose its functionality. Let's say that jQuery did this - that is, that it runs something like

```
const jQuery = (function() {
  // lots and lots of code
})();
export default jQuery;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

This contains a side-effect: the line

```
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

This means that other parts of your application could use `window.jQuery` without jQuery being specifically imported into that module. For example, you might have

```
// someModule.js
export const doStuff = () => {
  window.jQuery('div').text('Hi!');
};
```

And this can work without the line

```
import jQuery from 'jQuery';
```

inside the module script, because jQuery is on the window. (For this to work, there needs to be *at least one* module somewhere that does `import 'jQuery';` or something like that, so that jQuery's code that assigns itself to the window runs)

Because of the side-effect, Webpack will have a harder time with automatic tree-shaking - you'll have to [explicitly note](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) which modules depend on modules with side-effects.

In contrast, a module *without* dependency side-effects would be the `someModule.js` example above: all it does it *export a function*, without adding or changing functionality elsewhere.

So by "100% ESM module", Webpack is probably referring to scripts for which all modules' dependencies are *explicit* with `import` statements, instead of having to depend on side-effects (like a non-imported module assigning something to the window).

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular module syntax nodejs use.

Commonjs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html

```js
// exporting
module.exports.a = 1
// or, exports is an alias to module.exports, for all differences check out docs
exports.a = 1
// you can assign module.exports object as well, this sets what's exported
module.exports = {
  b: 2
}
// a is not exported anymore


// importing default import, imports module.exports object
const a = require('./b')
// or via named import
const {c} = require('./b');
```

ES modules: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html

```js
// names export
export const a = 1;

// default export
export default const b = 2;

// importing via name
import {a} from './c'

// importing default export
import c from './b'
```

Commonjs and esm are still in use. So we are not in %100 esm world yet.